# Javascript iniciar o código a partir de determinada linha

Tags: javascript, ajax

Tenho um código que percorre um arquivo .ofx para a leitura de suas marcações. No entanto, o código .ofx possui um header que impossibilita sua leitura (isto é, pra o código javascript funcionar tenho que retirar a header manualmente). Há algum meio de estabelecer a linha ao qual javascript vai iniciar uma função?

exemplo do .ofx:

```
OFXHEADER:100
DATA:OFXSGML
VERSION:102
SECURITY:NONE
ENCODING:USASCII
CHARSET:1252
COMPRESSION:NONE
OLDFILEUID:NONE
NEWFILEUID:NONE
<OFX>
<SIGNONMSGSRSV1>
<SONRS>
<STATUS>
<CODE>0</CODE>
<SEVERITY>INFO</SEVERITY>
</STATUS>
```

Eu queria que meu código ignorasse do `OFXHEADER:100` até `NEWFILEUID:NONE` e só começasse a funcionar a partir da tag `<OFX>`.

Estou usando este código para capturar as tags que desejo:

```
function loadOFXDoc() {
  var reader = new XMLHttpRequest();
  reader.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (reader.readyState == 4 && reader.status == 200) {
      showContent(reader);
    }
  };
  reader.open("GET", "sample.ofx", true);
  reader.send();
}
function showContent(xml) {
  var i;
  var ofxDoc = xml.responseXML;
  var table="<tr><th>Local</th><th>Valor</th></tr>";
  var x = ofxDoc.getElementsByTagName("STMTTRN");
  for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) {
    table += "<tr><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("MEMO")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td><td>" +
    x[i].getElementsByTagName("TRNAMT")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
    "</td></tr>";
  }
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;
}

loadOFXDoc();
```

Comment: Se recebes esse dado em um data pelo ajax, poderia transformar em string, capturar o header e excluí-lo?

Comment: Podes dar um exemplo de como usas o conteúdo (no caso de já teres filtrado a parte que queres)?

Comment: Vai ter que tratar isso manualmente, ainda mais se esta utilizando uma função nativa para processar esse conteúdo, que eu acredito ser xml... Mas o interessante seria você postar o código, pois pelo que entendi, está perguntando se é possivel modificar o comportamento de determinada função, sem ao menos especificar qual função seria esta.....

Comment: Opa, moçada. Com esse código tenho uma tabela com duas colunas mostrando o local da compra e o valor. NO ENTANTO, esse código apenas funciona se eu retirar na mão o header do arquivo .ofx. Meu objetivo é que o próprio script faça isso, ignore o header e só comece a ler a partir da tag `<OFX>`.

Comment: @InaldoEleuterio a minha pergunta é *"Podes dar um exemplo de como usas o conteúdo (no caso de já teres filtrado a parte que queres)?"*

Comment: @Sergio♦, desculpa mas não entendi. Como eu uso o conteúdo? Tá, vamos lá: as informações que pego são do cartão de crédito. Consegui filtrar pelas tags local de compra e preço. Elas são mostradas em uma div com duas colunas. Apenas. Seria isso?

Answer (score -1):

O problema não é o cabeçalho do arquivo *.ofx, é porque o arquivo não tem o cabeçalho do XML. Se o cabeçalho XML não ser declarado no arquivo, o mesmo não é interpretado.

De acordo com essa [página](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseXML) você pode usar o método `overrideMimeType` para forçar o arquivo à ser interpretado como XML, sem precisar declarar o cabeçalho XML.

```
reader.overrideMimeType('text/xml');
reader.send();
```

---

*Opcional*:

Outra solução também é usar um interpretador de XML para interpretar o texto normal do arquivo. Escrevi um [interpretador XML](http://pastebin.com/479n3VGD) para responder sua pergunta.

Answer (score -1):

você pode usar uma substring para remover o texto inicial, após isto basta fazer um Parse no documento.

```js
var data = document.querySelector("template").innerHTML;
var blob = new Blob([data], { type: "application/x-ofx" });
var _url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);

var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
http.open("GET", _url, true);
http.addEventListener("readystatechange", function (event) {
  if (http.readyState == 4) {
    var index = http.responseText.indexOf("<ofx>");
    var _text = http.responseText.substring(index);
    
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var ofxDoc = parser.parseFromString(_text, "text/xml");
    
    // realizando uma busca simples no documento ofx.
    var severity = ofxDoc.querySelector("ofx sonrs status severity");
    console.log(severity.textContent);
  }
});
http.send();
```

```html
<template>
  OFXHEADER:100
  DATA:OFXSGML
  VERSION:102
  SECURITY:NONE
  ENCODING:USASCII
  CHARSET:1252
  COMPRESSION:NONE
  OLDFILEUID:NONE
  NEWFILEUID:NONE
  <OFX>
    <SIGNONMSGSRSV1>
      <SONRS>
        <STATUS>
          <CODE>0</CODE>
          <SEVERITY>INFO</SEVERITY>
        </STATUS>
      </SONRS>
    </SIGNONMSGSRSV1>
  </OFX>
</template>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    var textoPattern = /<BANKTRANLIST>.*<\/BANKTRANLIST>/;
    var objetoRegex  = new RegExp(textoPattern, 'g');
    resultado = objetoRegex.exec(reader.result.replace(/[\n\r]+/g, ''));
```